# Best way to import .module.scss classes in react?

Tags: reactjs, sass, next.js, css-modules, react-css-modules

I'm working on a NextJs project and I've seen 2 ways of importing css classes from a .module.scss file.

Option 1:

```
import * as styles from './page.module.scss';

Classes used like this: 
<div className={styles.myClass} />
```

Option 2:

```
import {myClass} from './page.module.scss';

Classes used like this:
<div className={myClass} />
```

I've always used option 2, as it looks much cleaner to just write the class name in the render instead of having loads of 'styles.' everywhere.

However i've come to learn that option 2 does not work with storybook for some reason? In order to get it to work, I have to write this as a workaround:

```
import styles from './page.module.scss';
const { myClass } = styles;
```

So i'm wondering, what is the difference between the 2 on a functional level?

Comment: I think it might have something to do with the webpack config for your storybook

Answer (score 0):

On a code basis, there is no difference between the two. Both involve destructuring the objects during importation.